# Filtering data for any character that begins with what the user input using vba access

Tags: sql, ms-access, vba

Hello everyone I am trying to filter data in a table using vba where I have a split form setup. My goal is to filter data where the user can input a character such as "a" for the "FirstName" field and have results from the table filtered with persons first name that starts with "a". I have modified the code that I had setup with the help of a fellow member for comparing exact values to incorporate any value. Here is my code so far for one of the text boxes.

```
Private Sub txtFirstName_DblClick(Cancel As Integer)

If Me.Filter = "" Then
'Compares the values that begin with the input values in txtFirstName
'text box from the table field name FirstName
Me.Filter = FirstName & " LIKE '" & txtFirstName & "*'"
Else
'this line is suppose to append all the filtered data that were acquired
Me.Filter = Me.Filter & AND LastName & " LIKE '" & txtLastName & "*'"

End If

FilterOn = True

End Sub
```

I get an error in the else statement and please note that I am linking this form to an SQL server so I can not delete or modify existing data in the table I am a novice at this so I am still learning. I have seen similar post to questions like this but I am looking for a specific post related to this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are missing some quote symbols.

The `If` block should be:

`Me.Filter = "FirstName LIKE '" & txtFirstName & "*'"`

The `else` block should be:

`Me.Filter = Me.Filter & " AND LastName LIKE '" & txtLastName & "*'"`

Comment: Thank you I knew I misplaced the quotes.